# SEBS model in pcraster

Tags: python, canopy

I need the SEBS model for my graduate article and find it in http://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/projects/applications/sebs/.  install all software it need and verify all successful,but when I run the model in Canopy suggestted in PCraster web, a problem called "NameError: name 'readmap' is not defined " occurred. just like below:

**from pcraster import*
import numpy

### %run "D:\Program Files\SEBS5\pcrsebs50.py"

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Program Files\SEBS5\pcrsebs50.py in ()
    537 # Define inputs
    538 # maps
--> 539 DEM = readmap(guiInputMap('DEM','./example/dem90.map')) # Digital Elevation Model [m]
    540 nd = readmap(guiInputMap('NDVI','./example/ndvi90.map')) # NDVI map [-]
    541 T = readmap(guiInputMap('Surface Temperature [K]','./example/tkin90.map')) # Surface temperature [Kelvin]
NameError: name 'readmap' is not defined**

What is wrong with it , can you show me a detail operation about dealing with the model. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation 'readmap' is not defined.  This means that you need to tell your system where to find both the pcraster bin and the pcraster python directories.  The bin directory has the pcraster program and the python has the python library that comes with pcraster.

Under windows you would do this under advanced settings in control panel for environment variables.  Essentially you are going to add the pcraster_4.0.2 /bin directory to the end of your PATH variable.  If you don't have PYTHONPATH in your environmental variables, you'll add that as a new environment variable with the full directory to your pcraster-4.0.2 python directory.

Final notes: new entries on a string of directories are separated by ; (semi-colon). The directory you are pointing to does not have a trailing /. so if your pcraster is in program files as your above suggests, then it would look something like:

;d:\program files\pcraster-4.0.2\bin -> this for PATH
;d:\program files\pcraster-4.0.2\python -> this for PYTHONPATH (without the leading the leading ; if you don't already have a PYTHONPATH (perhaps pointing to another version of python))

Now, the above should work for your windows environment.

Comment: It works well,thanks. and do you have used the SEBS model above, I have some questions with this model. waiting for reply.

Comment: No, Logan.  Not SEBS, per se, but PCRaster in relation to several different hydrological models, Delft Fews, WFlow, LISEM, where evapotranspiration comes into play a a variable.   Were I in your position, I would read every article cited in your link above, search up any other journal references to SEBS and PCRaster.  I would also contemplate setting up a virtualBox in Ubuntu or Debian as a guest on your windows machine and just knuckle down and do this stuff in linux.  It'll take you a little time to feel comfortable but the documentation generally points to things linux which is better for u

Comment: I am currently wrestling with subsetting netCDF opendap served files to get bounding-boxed data and write that out as .tss.  If you know anything about that I'd be all ears.  But back to the articles, the Karssenberg, and the two Van der Qwast should be of help.  Articles that reference PCRaster can be strangely useful in detail of how someone got something to work in PCRaster. And afterall, what's a little more reading when you're going for a thesis...

Comment: I will try this. Thanks, I am a newer with Pcraster and Python :(.@Chris